# why newlib / libc source artificially confuses the C syntax

Tags: c

I am working on implementing custom File IO, and have noticed the source of newlib is complete mess.

They define everything like this:

```
#define _PTR        void *
#define _AND        ,
#define _NOARGS     void
#define _CONST      const
#define _VOLATILE   volatile
#define _SIGNED     signed
#define _DOTS       , ...
#define _VOID void
#define _READ_WRITE_RETURN_TYPE int
```

and then use it like

```
#define _DEFUN_VOID(name)       name(_NOARGS)
#define _CAST_VOID (void)
#define _EXFNPTR(name, proto)       (* name) proto
```

and then you get inconsistent mess like this:

```
_READ_WRITE_RETURN_TYPE _EXFNPTR(_write, (struct _reent *, _PTR,
                        const char *,
                        _READ_WRITE_BUFSIZE_TYPE));
```

Is there some real benefit of garbling the code this way? Or some historical reasons?

It seems to me that any pretence of portability is moot, considering they're absolutely inconsistent across the library.

Comment: That's just someone trying to be smart and failing miserably.

Comment: put on hold haha yea I guess it had it coming. Would welcome some opinions why is it so, though.

Comment: The only reason I can see for this is that you rarely read the system header files, there is an overwhelming documentation on them already on the internet so it's ok to be unreadable. Since the newlib seems to target a lot of various platforms if you define macros for all basic things it will be easier to port to new compilers supporting more or less features of C. And last but not least, it is easier for an automated script to parse these files, where for example `_EXFUN` always means a function declaration. It's generally inconsistent, but let's not forget that this is still work in progress

Comment: Uppercase fetishist. _ptr, _and are misleading, _dots too, but some find letters more readable. _return_type may be an attempt of abstraction/generalization. In general I quote @fritzone.

Comment: @fritzone: It seems you are tossing documentation on *standard functions* and documentation on *newlib headers* into one basket. Yes, the standard is well-documented, and clients can *use* newlib well enough. The newlib *sources* aren't that well-documented, and I tend to disagree on it "being OK to be unreadable" for *any* source... ;-)

Comment: Voting to reopen, by the way. The question is not asking for *our* opinion, it is asking for the reason the source was written that way. This can be answered "correctly", e.g. by linking to appropriate docs / mailing list entries about the decision.

Comment: @DevSolar do you have some such link in mind?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps the intent was to be able to use preprocessing to output some other variety of the code; or help with analysis by automated tools

Comment: @M.M: I only had a *brief* look at the sources of both newlib and glibc, shuddered in suppressed anguish, and [wrote my own C library](http://pdclib.e43.eu/). :-D As such, no, I cannot fathom the design decisions that went into those. I'd be interested to hear about them, though. ;-)

Comment: From reopen review, I'm choosing to leave this closed.  If appropriate authoritative sources are found, please link them in a comment and @-ping me and I'll vote to reopen.